# Multiple SQL languages within a single database or table?

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to use different SQL languages (eg. MySQL, MsSQL...) within one database, or even within one table?

If so, how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: No.  Can you explain why you are wanting to?

Comment: @BrandonMoore The intention was to use MySQL for most of the database, but use a different database language for something else, however it's not absolutely neccessary.

Comment: Ok, well depending on the situation if you find another dbms more handy for a certain operation then using the other database for a certain task may be an option.  But this question is similar to asking if you could write c++ code and compile it in c# or vice versa.

Comment: @AndriyM: I thought it could be a poorly worded question and they really did mean like the other question. However, comment #2 happened around the time I posted which clarifies it.

Comment: Which "different database language" did you have in mind?

Comment: I haven't researched it yet; if I can't use multiple RDBMS I am not tranferring the whole website to mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each SQL dialect is specific to the RDBMS it is used in. While they are all based on SQL, they do have their differences.

Unless you are talking about making your own RDBMS, I would say the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant. All the databases follow SQL, but there will be specific statements/functions which are specific to particular databases - which you cannot cross-use.

But you can link few databases. Eg: you can call data of one database from another database. I hope this is not your requirement.